# How to make my code calculate q2-LOO faster?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython, scikit-learn

I have some code I've written to calculate the q2-Leave One Out for a multiple linear regression, and it works quite well in terms of accuracy.  However, since I'm using q2LOO in a genetic algorithm as an evaluation metric, this code is way too slow -- right now, a decent GA run using my q2LOO code will take HOURS.  I haven't been able to find any libraries that calculate q2LOO, so mine uses numpy and scikit-learn.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
def mlrr(x_of_trainingset,y_actual):
    npones=np.ones(len(x_of_trainingset), float)

    A_sl=x_of_trainingset
    A=np.column_stack([A_sl,npones])

    lstsq,residuals,rank,something=np.linalg.lstsq(A, y_actual)
    return lstsq
def kfoldmlr(xi,yi,nfolds):
    x=xi.values
    y=yi.values

    kf = cross_validation.KFold(len(y), n_folds=nfolds)#indices=None, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
    y_hats=[]
    for train_index, test_index in kf:
        x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
        y_train=y[train_index]
        coefficients=mlrr(x_train,y_train)
        yhat=coefficients[-1]

        for index in range(x_test.size):
            slopetimesx=x_test[0][index]*coefficients[index]
            yhat=yhat+slopetimesx
        y_hats.append(float(yhat))


    stack=np.asarray(y_hats)
    return stack
def q2loo_mlr(x,y):
'''calculates q2loo of a linear regression of x and y where both x and y are 1-d'''
    yhats=kfoldmlr(x,y,len(x))
    PRESS=sum((y-yhats)**2)
    TSS=sum((y-np.mean(y))**2)
    r2cv=(TSS-PRESS)*(TSS**(-1))#1-(PRESS/TSS)
    return r2cv
```

after testing, this is the speed I get:

```
%timeit q2loo_mlr(x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop

%timeit kfoldmlr(x, y, len(x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 156 µs per loop
```

obviously the slowness is due to the fact that it's doing np.linalg.lstsq over and over again, but is there any alternative?  Or are there any other ways I could speed this up?

Comment: Using `np.sum` instead of just `sum` usually makes a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the runtimes of `q2loo_mlr` to `kfoldmlr` are 139:1 I would not think that the calls to `mlrr` in `kfoldmlr` are obviously slowing the code down - `kfoldmlr` is only called once.

If it was, caching the coefficients for a fixed index `train_index` would be an idea, as the coefficients seem to be a function of `train_index` alone, and thus could be re-used.

In `q2loo_mlr`, if you rewrite

```
TSS=sum((y-np.mean(y))**2)
```

as

```
y_mean = np.mean(y)
TSS=sum((y - y_mean)**2)
```

would that lower the runtime? As far as I understand `np.mean(y)` is a scalar.